# Matching two strings where some text is optional to match?

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to write a simple Java function that will take a list of Language Inputs and see if what I obtained from a database query matches. All of the strings in my database have been normalized to make searches easier. Here is an example.

Research Lab A wants participants that have any of the following language inputs (they are separated by the pipe character `|` ):

```
{English | English, Spanish | Spanish}
```

In other words, this lab can take participants that are either monolingual English, monolingual Spanish, or bilingual English and Spanish. This is very straightforward - if they database result returns `"English"` or `"English, Spanish"` or `"Spanish"`, my function will find a match.

HOWEVER, my database also marks if a participant only has minimal language input for some language (using the `~` character).

```
"English, ~Spanish" = participant hears English and a little Spanish
"English, ~Spanish, Russian" = participant hears English, Russian, and a little Spanish
```

This is where I am having trouble. I want to match something like `"English, ~Spanish"` with both `"English"` and `"English, Spanish"`.

I was thinking of just remove/hiding the languages with a marked `~`, but if there is a research lab that wants only `{English, Spanish}`, then `"English, ~Spanish"` will not match, even though it should.

I also cannot think of how I could use regular expressions to do this task. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so your problem is you don't know what reges you should use to match "English, ~Spanish"?

Comment: No, the function needs to take any arbitrary list of language inputs and determines if the queried result matches. I only used English and Spanish as an example. If I got the input {Russian | English}, then possible matches are: "Russian", "English", "Russian, ~German", "Russian, ~Spanish, ~Italian", etc.

Comment: The problem is that this is a lousy way to use regex in the first place. Your database is not properly normalized. You should not have comma-separated lists of multiple values, but multiple records of single values. Regex solutions for the above will be a) very (!) complex b) therefore hard to maintain c) slow. Try fixing your database and you can solve this with a single basic SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, I kind of suspected the same. If I create multiple records of single values, how would I know how many records I need though?

Comment: Why do you care how many records you need? Databases are designed to handle many records, that's nothing you should be concerned about. I don't know enough about your database so I can't recommend a better design. You should ask a "how to re-design my database" question. People here give good advice how to do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
\b(English[, ~]+Spanish|Spanish|English)\b
```

**Code**

```
try {
    if (subjectString.matches("(?im)\\b(English[, ~]+Spanish|Spanish|English)\\b")) {
        // String matched entirely
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

**Explanation**

```
"\\b" +               // Assert position at a word boundary
"(" +                // Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
                        // Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      "English" +          // Match the characters “English” literally
      "[, ~]" +            // Match a single character present in the list “, ~”
         "+" +                // Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      "Spanish" +          // Match the characters “Spanish” literally
   "|" +                // Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      "Spanish" +          // Match the characters “Spanish” literally
   "|" +                // Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      "English" +          // Match the characters “English” literally
")" +
"\\b"                 // Assert position at a word boundary
```

**UPDATE**

*A more generalized form would be something like this:*

```
(?-i)\b([A-Z][a-z]+[, ~]+[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+)\b
```

BTW, doing so you might be messed up, as this pattern would going to match a all Capitalized word. There might be a better option to do so by using this syntax while generating your RegEx pattern.

```
(A[, ~]+B|A|B)
```

Where `A`, `B` would be name of languages. I think this would be a better approach.

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising. I forgot to explain that we won't always be matching just the languages English and Spanish. I'm trying to figure out how I wouldn't have to hard code "English" and "Spanish" into this. But if you have any further insight please let me know!

Comment: Also in the example above, "~English, Spanish" needs to match {English, Spanish} as well, but if you add the optional [~]+ in the beginning, then it will also match "~English, ~Spanish", which it should not!

Comment: @Cylian This is a problem that cannot be solved by any *reasonable* amount of regex. Even your "generalized approach" is wrong. What about four languages? What about different orders? What about whitespace? The OP's entire approach is doomed. Fixing the database is the way to solve this, nothing else will help.

Comment: @Tomalak: You're right sir! But we could able to generate All Possible Combinations and club those frags to create a ``Bigger`` but ``Accurate`` pattern for this case. In my generalized app. ``A``, ``B`` is nothing but just the starting of a finite series.

Comment: @Cylian Seriously. That something *could* be done does in no way imply that it *should* be done. A regex that solves different orders for an arbitrary amount of language names will grow *exponentially* in size. It will be so complex that nobody can handle it anymore, making SQL queries crawl. This is a "recommend a good solution for a problem" site, not a "use regex just because the OP thinks that will help him" one.